# Problem using Python client library for Plaid

Tags: python, django, plaid

I'm following the [tutorial](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-python), but I get an error when I use ***item_public_token_exchange***.

[itempublic_tokenexchange](https://plaid.com/docs/api/tokens/#itempublic_tokenexchange)

```
exchange_request = ItemPublicTokenExchangeRequest(
    public_token=plaid_token
)
exchange_response = CLIENT.item_public_token_exchange(exchange_request)
```

the error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='sandbox', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /item/public_token/exchange (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10f1493a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

Not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are trying to connect to `sandbox` instead of `sandbox.plaid.com`. Make sure you have your host set up as `plaid.Environment.Sandbox` (or, alternatively, `sandbox.plaid.com`) and not just `sandbox`.